# Drill JDBC zookeeper timeout error

Tags: hadoop, jdbc, apache-zookeeper, apache-drill

The code of executing Drill query via jdbc IF runs w/o errors:

```
//val hdpConf = new Configuration()
//val fs = FileSystem.get(hdpConf)
runDrillJdbc()
```

But if I will **uncomment** lines with creating **fs instance**, the code blows with following error when creating connection `DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcUri)`:

```
16/01/26 08:41:10 ERROR ConnectionState: Connection timed out for connection string (xx:xx) and timeout (5000) / elapsed (5325)
oadd.org.apache.curator.CuratorConnectionLossException: KeeperErrorCode = ConnectionLoss
    at oadd.org.apache.curator.ConnectionState.checkTimeouts(ConnectionState.java:198)
    at oadd.org.apache.curator.ConnectionState.getZooKeeper(ConnectionState.java:88)
    at oadd.org.apache.curator.CuratorZookeeperClient.getZooKeeper(CuratorZookeeperClient.java:115)
    at oadd.org.apache.curator.utils.EnsurePath$InitialHelper$1.call(EnsurePath.java:148)
    at oadd.org.apache.curator.RetryLoop.callWithRetry(RetryLoop.java:107)
    at oadd.org.apache.curator.utils.EnsurePath$InitialHelper.ensure(EnsurePath.java:140)
    at oadd.org.apache.curator.utils.EnsurePath.ensure(EnsurePath.java:99)
    at oadd.org.apache.curator.framework.imps.NamespaceImpl.fixForNamespace(NamespaceImpl.java:74)
    at oadd.org.apache.curator.framework.imps.NamespaceImpl.newNamespaceAwareEnsurePath(NamespaceImpl.java:87)
    at oadd.org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl.newNamespaceAwareEnsurePath(CuratorFrameworkImpl.java:468)
    at oadd.org.apache.curator.framework.recipes.cache.PathChildrenCache.<init>(PathChildrenCache.java:223)
    at oadd.org.apache.curator.framework.recipes.cache.PathChildrenCache.<init>(PathChildrenCache.java:182)
    at oadd.org.apache.curator.x.discovery.details.ServiceCacheImpl.<init>(ServiceCacheImpl.java:65)
    at oadd.org.apache.curator.x.discovery.details.ServiceCacheBuilderImpl.build(ServiceCacheBuilderImpl.java:47)
    at oadd.org.apache.drill.exec.coord.zk.ZKClusterCoordinator.<init>(ZKClusterCoordinator.java:104)
    at oadd.org.apache.drill.exec.client.DrillClient.connect(DrillClient.java:185)
    at org.apache.drill.jdbc.impl.DrillConnectionImpl.<init>(DrillConnectionImpl.java:134)
    at org.apache.drill.jdbc.impl.DrillJdbc41Factory.newDrillConnection(DrillJdbc41Factory.java:66)
    at org.apache.drill.jdbc.impl.DrillFactory.newConnection(DrillFactory.java:69)
    at oadd.net.hydromatic.avatica.UnregisteredDriver.connect(UnregisteredDriver.java:126)
    at org.apache.drill.jdbc.Driver.connect(Driver.java:72)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:270)
    ...
```

Note, I've hidden zk uri as it's irrelevant for particular case.

Answer (score 0):

Drill JDBC from Standart distribution is not fully compatible with MapR one's. Download JDBC from MapR site and setting up guava libs resolve the issue.